# deploy Typescript GraphQL in production issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, pm2, prisma

I have tried for a week to research and deploy my serve into production but always failed to compile, my server using Typescript, Nexus GraphQL, Prisma with docker-compose, when in development mode I can run smoothy with `ts-node-dev` before running my app for the first time, I need to activate the docker-compose of Prisma and then deploy the Prisma service and generated services, then I run `ts-node-dev`, it was work, but when I do it in `ts-node` for production, it was failed, I was trying using `pm2` as well but it does not work, because when I use `ts-node` it always failed to compile my server.

I have tried many things option in this open issue on pm2 GitHub [running typescript with pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3503)

i have tried this as well `pm2 start ts-node -- -P tsconfig.server.json ./src` which my tsconfig.server.json like this

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false
  }
}
```

and this is my base tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
         "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
          "sourceMap": true, 
          "outFile": "./",
          "outDir": "./dist",  
          "strictFunctionTypes": true,
          "strictBindCallApply": true,
          "noImplicitThis": true,                
          "alwaysStrict": true, 
          "skipLibCheck": true,  
          "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

it failed to compile after I run the command I mention above

and I have tried using PM2 ecosystem, it was still the same, nothing works
my ecosystem like this

```
{
    "script": "ts-node",
    "args": "./src"
}
```

does you all succeed in production with Typescript ?? 
can I know how do u deploy them?
it means for me if you share your experience for this :) and hope u can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using `tsc` to transpile your project. E.g. `tsc --outDir dist/` to create valid .js files in the dist folder. If there are any errors during transpilation you need to fix them.

After successful transpilation you can use node to serve your valid js from the dist folder. E.g. `node dist/src/index.js`.